# how to recreate the .net membership hmacsha1 hash in javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, asp.net-membership, cryptojs

I'm trying to reproduce the same hmacsha1 hash and base64 encoding from .net membership provider in a javascript function.  I've tried using crypto-js and am getting different results.  The .net code will hash "test" into "W477AMlLwwJQeAGlPZKiEILr8TA="

Here's the .net code

```
string password = "test";
HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
hash.Key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
string encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
```

And here's the javascript method I tried using crypto-js that does not produce the same output

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("test", "");
var encodedPassword = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```

How can I get my javascript hash to match the hash being generated from .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//not sure why crypt-js's utf16LE function doesn't give the same result
//words = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse("test");
//utf16 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.stringify("test");

function str2rstr_utf16le(input) {
  var output = [],
      i = 0,
      l = input.length;

  for (; l > i; ++i) {
    output[i] = String.fromCharCode(
      input.charCodeAt(i)        & 0xFF,
      (input.charCodeAt(i) >>> 8) & 0xFF
    );
  }

  return output.join('');
}

var pwd = str2rstr_utf16le("test");
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(pwd, pwd);

var encodedPassword = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
alert(encodedPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a key in .NET:

```
var secretKey = "";
var password = "test";

var enc = Encoding.ASCII;
System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(enc.GetBytes(secretKey));
hmac.Initialize();

byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(password);
var encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(buffer));
```

Edit: as @Andreas mentioned, your problem is the encoding. So you just need to replace UTF by ANSI in your own code:

```
string password = "test";
System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1();
hash.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("");
string encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password)));
```

Comment: He uses `password` as Key and Message. And your solution only gives the correct result because of the different encoding (`ASCII` instead of `Unicode`) - which is the real problem here.

Comment: You're right. I somehow totally missed how he does set the key (wrongly).

Comment: The .net method is the existing function in Umbraco that I cannot modify, so unfortunately I can't change it.  I can only try to replicate it in javascript.

Comment: so it looks like the difference is that crypto-js hashes with a utf-8 encoding and the .net library uses utf-16

Comment: Don't you just *love* this kind of oddness that's not your fault, but which can easily set you back a day? :) Is your answer actually the solution?

Comment: yeah, converting the pwd to utf16le before putting in the hash function works.  The encoding tip was the right clue to getting the solution.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer, just to make it an easier reference.